# EF Core 2.0 How to Configure Child with Two Parents

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There are two unusual relationships I am wrestling with.  I have not found a way to "tell" EF how to build its model properly.  I am using stripped down classes here to focus on the relationships.  They don't seem to be in the usual 1-1, 1-M, M-M mold.

**First**

```
public class Parent1 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Parent2 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OtherStuff { get; set; }

    public int Parent1Id { get; set; }
    public Parent1 Parent1 { get; set; }

    public int Parent2Id { get; set; }
    public Parent2 Parent2 { get; set; }
}

and my fluent API

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent1>()
.HasMany(c => c.Children)
.WithOne(d => d.Parent1)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.Parent1Id)
.IsRequired()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


modelBuilder.Entity<Parent2>()
.HasMany(c => c.Children)
.WithOne(d => d.Parent2)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.Parent2Id)
.IsRequired()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

EF doesn't seem to like cascading deletes from two directions.

**Second**

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OtherStuff { get; set; }

    public int Parent1Id { get; set; }    // Think "Mail to"
    public Parent Parent1 { get; set; }

    public int Parent2Id { get; set; }    // Think "Bill To".  Same table, different purpose
    public Parent Parent2 { get; set; }
}

and my fluent API

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
.HasMany(c => c.Children)
.WithOne(d => d.Parent1)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.Parent1Id)
.IsRequired()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
.HasMany(c => c.Children)
.WithOne(d => d.Parent2)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.Parent2Id)
.IsRequired()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

EF doesn't like pointing at TWO parents in the same entity either.

Comment: `EF doesn't seem to like cascading deletes from two directions.` Consider what happens when a delete cascades from one parent but the relationship with the other parent should be maintained. Databases don't like ambiguity.  I suggest redesigning the schema, breaking the model between different contexts, or not using EF for this particular data.

Comment: **First** looks to me like pretty standard M-M relationship and should work w/o aby problem. The issue with **Second** is (A) the collection nav property - it can't be shared and (B) at least one of the two cascade deletes must be turned off.

Comment: @Ivan <lightbulb> I could facilitate with a Join table for scenario 2.  Up to two parents per child with a relationship type perhaps (Mail To vs Bill To).  Compound "key" (unique) of parent/child/type.  That could work and also allow cascading deletes if a parent is removed.

Comment: @Dan, for scenario 1, here's the desired result.  If the parent in either table is deleted, remove the child.  However, I could code the actual delete logic to parse the children and remove IF the other parent is also deleted.  Or not allow deletes but "hide" the deleted parent.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me clarify my thinking.